# MeshLab: Remesh with a quad mesh where mesh spacing is inverse proportional to principal curvature

Tags: meshlab

I want to create a non-uniform quad mesh. Meaning the spacing of the quad mesh should be inverse proportional to the curvature (principal curvatures).
In other words, the higher the curvature, the smaller the distance between the quad edges.

Is this doable in MeshLab?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, that is not doable in meshlab. I suggest to try `instant meshes` instead.

https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes

Comment: Looked at the “instant mesh” youtube. Excellent I find the detection of sharp edges. But what I did no see, is a curvature dependent mesh spacing. The goal of this depenency is the reduction of quads in the mesh on flat or almost flat areas of the surface.